# Matching two values in separate spreadsheets and returning one value from one spreadsheet to the other

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

Spreadsheet A contains a zip code in Column M.  Spreadsheet B contains zip codes in Column A and a corresponding office in Column C.
I'd like to match Column M's cell value to the exact zip code in Spreadsheet B Column A and return the corresponding value in Spreadsheet B, column C (same row), into the column in Spreadsheet A where I am typing the formula which is a new column with no data.  Thanks much!.

Comment: have a look on [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 1):

The formula assumes that you start at 2nd row (M2) in Spreadsheet A and the table is at 'Spreadsheet B'!A2:C53 range. Update your table if it is necessary, then copy down to formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(M2,'Spreadsheet B'!A2:C53,3,0)
```

Comment: Add your  in the first row into a code sample to be better readable like this`'Spreadsheet B'!A2:C53 range`